Japanese Input, Mozc not working
I am not able to type in Japanese, Romanji on my keyboard. There was no Mozc option in the 'Add Input Method' option, so I also installed ibus-mozc package and it still isn't working. Any ideas on what I should try doing next?
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 
GNOME 46 
System Type: 64-bit 
Wayland

Never mind, it started working. Turns out after I download Japanese under the 'Language Support' option, the Japanese layout all were moved into one word 'Japanese' in the menu before clicking 'Other...'. I just didn't notice it and was still searching in the other keyboard list. Someone make an answer with this, and I'll mark it accepted.
